# I am not able to add Tomcat Server again

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I have removed my tomcat 7 server from eclipse(Kepler) and now trying to add different Tomcat 7 server in eclipse, but it is saying "The name is already in use. Specify a different name". 
What could be done in this case? Please suggest.

Comment: Try after restarting eclipse

Comment: I have already done that but no success

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/490005/ check this

Comment: Thanks, their solution worked for me. :)

Comment: you can close this question by your own answer.

Answer (score 11):

Close Eclipse
2. In {workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings delete the following two files:
org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs
3. Restart Eclipse

I hope it will solve the problem as it did with me.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in eclipse.

Delete

- org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs and
- org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs

in {workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings

Note: Sometimes you have more than one workspace. Ensure you check your current workspace and delete the above files from the correct "current" workspace.

Answer (score 1):

this problem happen when you delete tomcat from pc and eclipse still using it in project so eclipse tell you The name is already in use
solution
step 1: close eclipse
step2:go to {work space directory}:{projedirectory}.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings
and delete:
1==> org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs
2==> org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
step3: open eclipse and create new server
hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

After trying the other solutions, if Eclipse is recreating the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs`

file when you open Eclipse. Delete your configuration data stored in Eclipse Ooompf by clicking this button:

[image: Delete your configuration data stored in Eclipse Ooompf by clicking this button:]

Open My Account | Storage | Delete | Confirm Delete

Then close Eclipse, delete that file and reopen Eclipse.